# Using the actual datapoint as a center for Tikz Surface Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a very special question to all of you Tikz gods out there!

I'm trying to make a plot from 3D data and a view from above. In the end the image should look like a pattern plot with 5 x 5 different tiles, all in a color which corresponds to the `z` data.

When doing this with the `\addplot[surf]` function, tikz only outputs a 4 x 4 grid

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
    scale only axis,
    height=5cm,
    xtick = {-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
    colormap/blackwhite,
    colorbar right,
    axis equal image,
    mesh/rows=5,
    %shader=faceted interp,
    %patch type=bilinear,
    colormap/blackwhite,
    colorbar right,
]

\addplot3[surf]  coordinates {
(1, 1, 0.28)
(0.5, 1, 0.29)
(0, 1, 0.29)
(-0.5, 1, 0.25)
(-1, 1, 0.26)
(1, 0.5, 0.27)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.28)
(0, 0.5, 0.29)
(-0.5, 0.5, 0.29)
(-1, 0.5, 0.28)
(1, 0, 0.29)
(0.5, 0, 0.25)
(0, 0, 0.27)
(-0.5, 0, 0.25)
(-1, 0, 0.28)
(1, -0.5, 0.25)
(0.5, -0.5, 0.27)
(0, -0.5, 0.28)
(-0.5, -0.5, 0.29)
(-1, -0.5, 0.25)
(1, -1, 0.25)
(0.5, -1, 0.26)
(0, -1, 0.25)
(-0.5, -1, 0.28)
(-1, -1, 0.28)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...And this is the closest that i can get with cheating:-/

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
    scale only axis,
    height=5cm,
    xtick = {-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
    colormap/blackwhite,
    colorbar right,
    axis equal image,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    enlarge y limits=0.2,
]

\addplot3[mesh,scatter,mark=square*,mark size=14,black]  coordinates {
(1, 1, 0.28)
(0.5, 1, 0.29)
(0, 1, 0.29)
(-0.5, 1, 0.25)
(-1, 1, 0.26)
(1, 0.5, 0.27)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.28)
(0, 0.5, 0.29)
(-0.5, 0.5, 0.29)
(-1, 0.5, 0.28)
(1, 0, 0.29)
(0.5, 0, 0.25)
(0, 0, 0.27)
(-0.5, 0, 0.25)
(-1, 0, 0.28)
(1, -0.5, 0.25)
(0.5, -0.5, 0.27)
(0, -0.5, 0.28)
(-0.5, -0.5, 0.29)
(-1, -0.5, 0.25)
(1, -1, 0.25)
(0.5, -1, 0.26)
(0, -1, 0.25)
(-0.5, -1, 0.28)
(-1, -1, 0.28)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: using markers]

There must be any hidden feature, which allows me to do this cleanly with the surf function, right?

Thanks for reading this tldr post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `matrix plot` is what you want

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colormap/blackwhite,colorbar right]
            \addplot[matrix plot,mesh/cols=5,point meta=explicit]table[meta=z]{
                x       y       z
                1       1       0.28
                0.5     1       0.29
                0       1       0.29
                -0.5    1       0.25
                -1      1       0.26
                1       0.5     0.27
                0.5     0.5     0.28
                0       0.5     0.29
                -0.5    0.5     0.29
                -1      0.5     0.28
                1       0       0.29
                0.5     0       0.25
                0       0       0.27
                -0.5    0       0.25
                -1      0       0.28
                1       -0.5    0.25
                0.5     -0.5    0.27
                0       -0.5    0.28
                -0.5    -0.5    0.29
                -1      -0.5    0.25
                1       -1      0.25
                0.5     -1      0.26
                0       -1      0.25
                -0.5    -1      0.28
                -1      -1      0.28
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]